# Visual Studio 2022 - Test Explorer Loads Indefinitely

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2022

I had created a visual studio 2022 class library project. added a MSTest and everything worked.  One day, Test Explorer keeps loading.

After some search, some users indicate to remove the .vs folder and rebuild test project. did not work. ok.

Let me create a NEW solution with a class library then add a unit test to it.  open test explorer... loads indefinitely.

Create NEW solution with class library then open test explorer.  loads indefinitely.

the only thing now I can think of is uninstalling visual studio and reinstall all over again.  my god!

please help.